# How to redirect to another folder in htdocs?

Tags: php, redirect, htdocs

can somebody help me on how to redirect my user to another folder in htdocs.
my current page is at :

> http://maps/index.php

my goal is everytime user access that site they will be automatically redirected to:

> http://dev_maps/index.php

both `maps` and `dev_maps` folders are under htdocs of XAMPP.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to change the server or only the htdocs folder? you can edit http://maps/index.php script?

Comment: htdocs folder only..

Comment: can you edit the http://maps/index.php script really?

Comment: yes. maps/index.php is already existing. I just created new version in dev_maps so I want my user to be directed to dev_maps every time time access the maps folder

Answer (score 1):

You must place `<?php header('Location: http://dev_maps/index.php'); ?>` before opening the  tag. That is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is, in your http://maps/index.php write this code (only this code):

```
<?php header('Location: http://dev_maps/index.php'); ?>
```

The hard way is setting a virtual host or the redirection in the .htacces file